# Google Analytics Easy Tracker Issues

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to integrate Google Analytics on my Activities. 
As per the google docs I read up on EasyTracker and added EasyTracker.jar to my libs and referenced the same, extended my Activities from "TrackedActivity" / "TrackedListActivity"
Also made an entry in the strings.xml file located under values
`<string name="ga_api_key">UA-xxxxxxxx-x</string>`
But whenever I log into Google Analytics I don't see any tracking displayed there.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to track the pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytic 1st time appear on website after about 24-48 hours. So if you are waiting for analytic after implementation then just wait for 48 hours.

Comment: It worked thanks Arsian :)
But I am not able to see which page of the application is being visited on the Google Analytics WebSite. 
It always shows zero. ?

Comment: Please ask this in chat room. Thanks

Comment: Dont have 20 reputation as of now Arsian :)

Comment: If I do what I mentioned in my question, It just Tracks the Application Usage.
If I want to do a Page by Page Tracking.. I had to extend the onStart() Method call the same method of the super class in the beginning of the Function. And then go `EasyTracker.getTracker.trackPage("/MyPage");`
I might've made mistake in the method names above but its pretty much similar to the Code Example given on Google Analytics SDK Homepage

Comment: For a Page By Page tracking.. I used the EasyTracker Library in the way I mentioned above and it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

Add another string:

```
<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
```

And then check logcat to see any information from the Analytics library.

Answer (score 0):

did you give the following uses permission.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
        tracker.start("your analytics code", this.con);

        tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App");

        tracker.trackPageView("ur activity name");
        tracker.dispatch();
        tracker.stop();
```

Comment: SathishBabu S, According to Google if i have multiple activities i should use their Easy Tracker Library, which is supposed to handle everything